# WPF UI Animation Library

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a WPF library that can be used for animations?

It should support animating transitions from one WPF form to another (like flip effects etc) and also been able to animate toolbox components (like labels etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some effects and transitions libraries on Codeplex.

- http://wpffx.codeplex.com/
- http://transitionals.codeplex.com/

And this one which lets you transition between different UserControls.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197132/Simple-WPF-Page-Transitions

In fact, have a good scout around on Codeplex and CodeProject and you will find several other libraries that may help you out.

Comment: While I realize this answer was accepted and useful at the time, CodePlex no longer exists, and thus both of the codeplex links are now dead. Both projects seem to have been forked on GitHub, but I am not certain if either of the ones I found is an "official" continuation of its respective project or not. In general, though, searching nuget or github for WPF libraries can turn up many useful results for anyone with the same question in the future.

Comment: https://codeplexarchive.org/codeplex/ for anyone that needs codeplex stuff @dodexahedron

Answer (score 6):

Try having a look at [Transitionz](https://www.scichart.com/transitionz-wpf-free-library-metro-style-animation-effects/) which is a free open source WPF Animations library published and used by [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com).

[image: WPF Animate Position and Opacity on property changed]

It allows you to animate Opacity, Translate Transform, or Blur on attached property changed, on load, on visibility. With MVVM support allowing changes from a view model.

[image: WPF Animate Blur on property changed]

The Github wiki & source is here: https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Wpf.UI/wiki/Transitionz-Library

And NuGet is here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SciChart.WPF.UI.Transitionz/

Answer (score 2):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) controls got what you wan't, but I'll suggest you to give it a try to the native WPF Animations, it isn't that hard and it's included right out the box (for free). Obviously working with something like [Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) will make your work pretty easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try [XAMLFlair](https://github.com/XamlFlair/XamlFlair), it supports WPF and UWP.

Or [WPF Material Design](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/), on top of the material controls, it does come with an animation library.